# Phone is locked and says I need to wait for more than 2 weeks to unlock!

Tags: lumia, security

I locked myself out of my phone by entering the wrong password too many times. However, instead of the usual "Try again in 1 minute" message, it says I need to wait 24,135 minutes (more than 16 days)!

What can I do to unlock the phone today?

Comment: Had the same problem on my mom's phone awhile ago. Ended up taking it in to the nearest Microsoft Store (if none is nearby, maybe your cell carrier's store can help). I don't recall if they actually managed to work around the issue or not, but we ended up asking for the phone to be replaced regardless.

Comment: I presume by now you've tried shutting it down and turning it on again, and forcing a reboot via holding Lock+VolDn?

Comment: i dont know. my 2 years son did this with my phone. hate this windows, i am going to switch to android.

Comment: What model of phone is it? you should be able to do a hard reset, and set it up again, if the password is unknown to you.

Comment: Does the value 24,135 actually decrease? Or is it stuck at the number?

Comment: Does hard-reseting the phone actually work? If anyone comes across a solution please help. Also have the same problem

Answer (score 13):

i had the same problem but i finally overcame it. switch off the phone , re-insert the sim card and turn it ON. the phone will update to its current time and it will ask you to enter your password again

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug. You can try again in double of the time from the last attempt. So if it showed 1 minute, it would be in 2 minutes, after that 4 minutes etc.

I think it got fixed in GDR2 update but not 100% sure

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have enough battery power.
2. Power off your device and disconnect charger.
3. Connect charger and simultaneously press power and volume down buttons until an exclamation mark appears on screen.
4. Press the following buttons in order: Volume down, volume up, power, volume down.
5. Wait for phone to reset.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 buttons....volume down, and camera. Hold. Don't let go, now press the power button.  You should have a cog on screen . . Your phone is now wiped . Easier than sending it back !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version, but a simple reboot should reset the counter.

Comment: NO..turning your phone off then on again would defeat the meaning and purpose of a lock system.. This wont work