# my phone is locked and i need more than 800,000 minute to try again

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-535

i locked my phone by entering wrong password too many times and now is says i need 814453 minutes to try again. What do i do to unlock my phone today?

Comment: Try the answer here : http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3034/18061