# Nokia Windows Lumia 635 Locked Out, Forgot paswordd

Tags: lumia, security

My windows phone got locked out and i forgot the password, I turn it on and it is normal i try entering a password i know it says try again in 32 minutes! Please help

Comment: please someone answer

Comment: @KolappanNathan How?

Comment: See here : http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2280/phone-is-locked-and-says-i-need-to-wait-for-more-than-2-weeks-to-unlock