# My Lumia 520 is locked and says try again in 28000 minutes

Tags: lumia, lumia-520, security, password

My 2 year old daughter entered wrong password I don't know how many times and now it is saying to try again in 28000 minutes. I tried switching it off and on again a number of times but it didn't help.

Before anybody marks it as duplicate(and refers to this [answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2280/phone-is-locked-and-says-i-need-to-wait-for-more-than-2-weeks-to-unlock)) I'd like to let you know that I've tried those solutions and my phone is still locked.

Comment: Ddi you try the other solutions on there, such as http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/9090/106 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a Hard Reset on your phone. That seems to be the only way out. But be warned. It obliterates all the data in your phone...and you will start everything all over again, just like you got a new phone out of the box:

#### Hard Reset

> Press and hold <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> at the same time until you feel a vibration (about 10–15 seconds). Ignore the `slide down to power off` screen.
>   When you feel the vibration, release the buttons, and then immediately press and hold the <kbd>volume down</kbd> button until you see a large exclamation mark.
>
> Once the exclamation mark appears, press the following four buttons in this order: <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>, <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>,<kbd>Power</kbd> and <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>. 
>   Your phone should now reset and restart itself. It might take a while for the reset to finish. You should see gears/cogs turning on the display, to signify the process. It might take a while to finish.

This will DEFINITELY resolve your problem, but, at the expense of your data in your phone. You will have to re-download apps. Stuff like texts, contacts and pictures are automatically backed onto [OneDrive](http://onedrive.live.com) if you signed into your phone with a [Microsoft Account](https://account.microsoft.com/account), so you can recover that by signing in with the same account into your phone again after the rest. All the backed upp data will be restored.

You can check further instructions on **[How to perform soft and hard resets](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/wiki/mdlumia-mdsettings/how-to-soft-and-hard-reset-your-windows-phone/4ec36474-c21e-4aec-ad1b-30f3afaf824d)** in the [linked article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/wiki/mdlumia-mdsettings/how-to-soft-and-hard-reset-your-windows-phone/4ec36474-c21e-4aec-ad1b-30f3afaf824d)

Answer (score 0):

Reset your phone.
Important: Resetting your phone erases all personal content, including apps, and restores the factory settings.

> 1. Make sure your phone has enough battery power, charge your phone for at least 20 minutes.
> 2. Switch off your phone, and disconnect the charger.
> 3. Press and hold the volume down key, and connect the charger. An exclamation mark (!) is shown on the screen.
> 4. Press the keys in the following order: volume up, volume down, power, and volume down.
> 5. Wait for your phone to reset, during the reset there will be gears rotating on the screen for up to 5 minutes, after which the screen
>      goes blank for ~30 seconds and then your phone will restart.
> 6. Go through the initial phone setup, if the date and time are shown, ensure the values are correct.